# Run python script with libraries from nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js

I managed to run python script from nodejs using

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./script.py", "hello"]);
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

where script.py is :

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
sys.stout.flush()
```

But, in my script.py code, I'd also like to use external python libraries like yfinance (that gives stock prices) but whenever I import them in my python script, my nodejs program no longer works : for example, changing script.py to :

```
import sys
import yfinance as yf
print(sys.argv[1])
print(yf.Ticker("AAPL").history(period="1d",interval="1m")) 
sys.stout.flush()
```

should return to nodejs "hello" followed by a bunch of Apple stock prices from the last 24 hours

What should I do ?

Comment: Explain "no longer works". What happens, what should happen (edit the question)?

Comment: My nodejs program will simply stop.
In my python code, if I added :

import yfinance as yf
print(yf.Ticker("AAPL").history(period="1d",interval="1m"))

I should receive the Apple stock prices each minute from the last 24 hours in my nodejs program.

Comment: Probably remove the Node code and troubleshoot this in Python alone. Roughly speaking, you need to make sure the library you want to `import` is in Python's `sys.path`; try setting `PYTHONPATH` in the environment if it's not installed in a regular place. Perhaps also investigate Python's virtual environments, which let you easily package a project and its dependencies, sort of like (I believe) NPM.

Comment: will investigate that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it : yfinance library was not installed on Python (even though I had installed it on Anaconda, which is why it was working on my python IDE)

So I went to CMD and typed :

```
python -m pip install -U pip
pip install yfinance
```

and now it works just fine.